# Reading Delta Lake by partitions

Tags: rust, delta-lake

I have my data in ADLS v2. One table is over 3TB and it is partitioned by event_date, event_type and sample_freq. Since data is that big, it's natural that I would want to read it by partitions and not to fecth all the data in memory.

How would I read data by partitions using Rust? So far I tried using delta-rs. I managed to get the files uri by partition:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use deltalake::delta::open_table_with_storage_options;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

    let mut azure_storage_options = HashMap::new();
    azure_storage_options.insert("azure_storage_account_name".to_string(), 
                                 "name".to_string());
    azure_storage_options.insert("azure_storage_account_key".to_string(), 
                                 "key".to_string());
    
    let path = "az://name/path/to_data/";
    let table = open_table_with_storage_options(
        path,
        azure_storage_options
    ).await.unwrap();

    /* Get files of particular partition */
    let files = table.get_file_uris_by_partitions(&[deltalake::PartitionFilter {
        key: "event_date",
        value: deltalake::PartitionValue::Equal("2018-01-01")
    }])?;
    
    Ok(())
}
```

I was also looking into datafusion documentation, but I didn't see any way to specify partitions in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the result of `get_file_uris_by_partitions` method, which returns the URIS of the data files, to read the data from the files.

To read the data from the files, you can use the `ParquetFile` and `ParquetReader` structs provided by the `parquet-rs` library. Here's an example:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use deltalake::delta::open_table_with_storage_options;
use parquet::file::reader::SerializedFileReader;
use parquet::record::Row;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

    let mut azure_storage_options = HashMap::new();
    azure_storage_options.insert("azure_storage_account_name".to_string(), 
                                 "name".to_string());
    azure_storage_options.insert("azure_storage_account_key".to_string(), 
                                 "key".to_string());
    
    let path = "az://name/path/to_data/";
    let table = open_table_with_storage_options(
        path,
        azure_storage_options
    ).await.unwrap();

    /* Get files of particular partition */
    let files = table.get_file_uris_by_partitions(&[deltalake::PartitionFilter {
        key: "event_date",
        value: deltalake::PartitionValue::Equal("2018-01-01")
    }])?;
    
    /* Read data from the files */
    for file in files {
        let file_reader = SerializedFileReader::new(file.uri().to_string())?;
        let mut parquet_reader = ParquetReader::new(file_reader);
        while let Some(record) = parquet_reader.next() {
            let row = record?;
            /* Process the row */
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I had this idea as well. However, I thought that ParquetReader will not be able to access those uris, since he doesn't have permissions for that. He could get permissions by authenticating himself, but I haven't found the way how it's possible

Comment: To create a `ParquetReader` instance with credentials to access an ADLS account, you will need to use a combination of `azure_core`, `azure_identity`, `azure_storage_blob` and `parquet`

Answer (score 0):

Just an example code snippet that demonstrates how to use these libraries to create a ParquetReader instance with credentials to access an ADLS account:

```
use azure_core::prelude::*;
use azure_identity::prelude::*;
use azure_storage_blob::prelude::*;
use parquet::arrow::{ArrowReader, ParquetFileArrowReader};
use parquet::file::reader::{FileReader, SerializedFileReader};
use std::convert::TryInto;
use std::io::Cursor;

// Set Azure ADLS storage account credentials
let account_name = "<your_account_name>";
let account_key = "<your_account_key>";
let container_name = "<your_container_name>";
let blob_name = "<your_blob_name>";

// Create a BlobServiceClient instance with Azure AD credentials
let credential = DefaultCredential::new().unwrap();
let endpoint = format!("https://{}.blob.core.windows.net", account_name);
let client = BlobServiceClient::new_client(&endpoint, credential);

// Get a reference to the Blob Container
let container_client = client.as_container_client(container_name);

// Create a ParquetReader instance
let blob_client = container_client.as_blob_client(blob_name);
let blob = blob_client.get().await.unwrap();
let mut reader = Cursor::new(blob.data);
let parquet_reader = SerializedFileReader::new(&mut reader).unwrap();
let arrow_reader = ArrowReader::new(parquet_reader);
let parquet_file_reader = ParquetFileArrowReader::new(Arc::new(arrow_reader));
```